# dynamic_sidebar not Showing on page

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I was trying to add the Sidebar by adding this code to the Functions.php of theme

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
 register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Company Single Sidebar', 'responsive'),
        'description' => __('Area 12 - company-singlesidebar.php', 'responsive'),
        'id' => 'company-singlesidebar',
        'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>'
    ));
}
```

And after that i add this code to the template page.

```
        <div class="contant_right_wrap">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('company-singlesidebar');?>
        </div>
```

The Sidebar is shown in the Widget but not showing on the Page.

Comment: Did you add a widget to the sidebar in the back-end

Comment: yes i added the Two text widget in the sidebars. Is we have to created the new PHP page for this sidebars. @Pieter Goosen

Comment: No. Have you inspected your page to verify that it is actually there, might be hidden by css

Answer (score 1):

Just a few tips here:

- You don't need to wrap your sidebar registration in a `if(function_exists())` conditional statement. `register_sidebar` is a core function, so it will always exists.
- When registering a sidebar, it is always good practice to do it inside a function and then hooking that function to the `widgets_init` hook

Apart from that, your code should work

Comment: Any progress on this problem?